# how to get Emacs to stop saving org-agenda as a file?

Tags: org-mode, auto-save

In my directory I keep on winding up with dozens of files with names like these:

```
#%2AOrg%20Agenda%2A#12182wk#
#%2AOrg%20Agenda%2A#13353nN#
#%2AOrg%20Agenda%2A#13568-1B#
```

The content of which is this:

```
Week-agenda (W20):
Monday     11 May 2015 W20
Tuesday    12 May 2015
Wednesday  13 May 2015
Thursday   14 May 2015
Friday     15 May 2015
Saturday   16 May 2015
Sunday     17 May 2015
```

I believe they're getting created when I run save-some-buffers, which I do to save all open files I'm working with.

I'm trying to get Emacs to ignore my org-agenda files when saving, but my attempt isn't working:

http://pastebin.com/UPVrGgLf

Comment: I don't think this is default behaviour. You're probably using an ill-defined function that saves all buffers.

Comment: You're right. I figured out they're getting saved when I run save-some-buffers. I'm updating the question.

Comment: How about posting your custom/modified `save-some-buffers`-related settings (that I presume was the result [in part or in whole] of a prior thread in another forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254414/how-to-silently-save-all-buffers-in-emacs ), and focus on how to exclude certain non-file-visiting-buffers from those custom settings that you run (which are probably *not* org-mode specific)?

Comment: @lawlist Good call. Here's what I got:  
http://pastebin.com/UPVrGgLf

Comment: The function `org-save-all-org-buffers` uses the test `(lambda () (derived-mode-p 'org-mode))` to constitute the second *optional* argument to `save-some-buffers`.  Essentially, **all** `org-mode` buffers will be saved irregardless of whether a buffer is file-visiting or non-file-visiting.  The doc-string for `save-some-buffers` states that the optional second argument named `PRED` can have three possible values:  [continued underneath . . .]

Comment: "***[1]** If PRED is nil, all the file-visiting buffers are considered.  **[2]** If PRED is t, then certain non-file buffers will also be considered.  **[3]** If PRED is a zero-argument function, it indicates for each buffer whether to consider it or not when called with that buffer current.*"  So, you need to modify `org-save-all-buffers` or create a new function that uses your preferred `PRED`.

Comment: @lawlist How do I do that?

Comment: Copy `org-save-all-org-buffers` to your `*scratch*` buffer, and rename it to `peter-org-save-all-org-buffers`.  Replace `(lambda () (derived-mode-p 'org-mode))` with your own `lambda` function that does what you want [either you or another forum participant will need to write this function].  Save your new function in your `.emacs` or the equivalent thereof if you are using Aquamacs still.  Change your hook so that it refers to your new function instead of the stock function.  Restart Emacs.  You can find the stock function with `M-x find-function`

Comment: If you are using `save-some-buffers` separately (e.g., with a keyboard shortcut), then your second argument to that function -- i.e., `PRED` -- will need to be modified to suit your needs (perhaps by using a `lambda` function similar to what you use in the above-comment).  You probably do *not* want to run `org-save-all-org-buffers` or `peter-org-save-all-org-buffers` *every single time* an `org-mode` buffer gets opened -- i.e., I would not recommend using an `org-mode-hook` or an `org-agenda-mode-hook` with that function.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of that, so I removed the mode hooks, did `(setq buffer-save-without-query nil)` and rebound A-s to `save-all-org-buffers`. Will that be sufficient?

Comment: @lawlist I took your advice and stopped using `save-some-buffers` and instead switched to `save-all-org-buffers`. How can I create a function that will save not only org-mode buffers, but also emacs-lisp buffers?

Comment: And to also save the file `.abbrev_defs`

Comment: I added another example to an existing thread that I believe is related entitled **how to silently “Save All Buffers” in Emacs?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30468232/2112489  It is not designed to be used with any hooks (although it *could* be), but instead to be called interactively with a keyboard shortcut or with `M-x . . .`